# Find files (not) containing text pattern on a specified line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, find

I'm trying to search through a set of text files and return the names of files that **on a specified line** contain a text pattern OR do not contain the text on the specified.
In my case I need to return the filenames of files whose last line does not contain the text pattern.

file1.txt

> line1 abc
> line2 must have

file2.txt

> line1 must have
> line2 return me

the function/command, when passed "must have", should return ONLY file2.txt, because it does not contain "must have" on the last line.

Comment: I think instead of 'specified line' you want to say 'last line', throughout?

Answer (score 1):

To check the contents of the last line of each file in the current directory, use `tail` and `grep`:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  tail -1 -- "$file" | grep -q "must have" || printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

This assumes your text files are named ending with `.txt`; adjust that wildcard as needed. The `tail -1` grabs the last line of the file (seeking backwards, which is more efficient than potentially reading forwards through the file); that line is then piped to `grep` to look for the desired text. The `-q` flag to grep tells it to be quiet about its work, and simply set the return code accordingly. If grep does *not* find a match, then the `||` "or" alternation tells the shell to execute `printf`, which prints the filename.

You could put that code in a script or in a function:

```
lastlinehas() {
  for file in *.txt
  do
    tail -1 -- "$file" | grep -q "$1" || printf '%s\n' "$file"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`:

```
$ awk 'ENDFILE { if ($0 !~ /must have/) print FILENAME }' file2.txt file1.txt
file2.txt
```

This uses a `ENDFILE` block to test the current contents of `$0` (the last line of the file that we just reached the end of) against the regular expression `must have`.  If there is no match, the filename is printed.

The `ENDFILE` block is not available in BSD `awk` or `mawk`.

Using standard `awk`:

```
for fname in *.txt; do
    awk 'END { if ($0 !~ /must have/) print FILENAME }' "$fname"
done
```

This works similarly as the GNU `awk` solution, but invokes `awk` once for each file.